# Obtaining a HERE Maps Embed code for reuse

Tags: html, maps, embed

Can someone tell me how I get a simple embed code from here maps? I simply can't find the Embed button which in my opinion should be there on any map website. Ironically I'm making a website for here so I'm not allowed to get a google map.

Comment: Also check out the nice collection of examples: heremaps.github.io/examples

Answer (score 4):

For a simple static HERE Map you should look at the [Map Image API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-image) - this will embed a simple image. However if you want a moveable map, you can use the [HERE Maps API for JavaScript](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/overview.html) in an `IFrame` and pass the latitude, longitude and zoom level of your choice e.g. something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"
    src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"
    src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"
    src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  charset="UTF-8"
    src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: grey" />
  <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >


/**
 * Obtains a value from a query string
 * @param  {String} name key in the query string
 * @return {String}      value
 */
function getParameterByName(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,  '\\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\\]');
  var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]'  + name + '=([^&#]*)'),
  results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results === null ? '' :
    decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

/**
 * Moves the map to display at  agiven location
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function moveMap(map, location, zoom){
    var lat = getParameterByName('lat'),
    lng = getParameterByName('lng');
    zoom = getParameterByName('zoom');

  map.setCenter({lat: lat, lng: lng});
  map.setZoom(zoom);
}


/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: '<YOUR APP ID>',
  app_code: '<YOUR APP CODE>',
  useHttps: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map);

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
moveMap(map);


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `Iframe` can be called specifying the height and width:

```
<iframe src=".../path-to-file/embed.html?lat=40.7057&lng=-73.9306&zoom=12" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

The result is something like this:

[image: Embedded New York]

Of course you could then add in all the usual other stuff as well, such as adding markers and so on, to make the map do what **you** want, not just what the provider offers. Why should you be restricted to a single look-and-feel as offered by the map provider?

Comment: i know im kind of necro posting here but as an observation. here has a long way to go towards being developer friendly in this case. that is a LOT of assets to pass on the page for very minimal results.